# Is there a way to apply default HTML values with JavaScript when something happens?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an application where a Dictionary fetch query dynamically changes things on screen. For example, if the user types a word which doesn't exist, I want a placeholder to show an error message in a red color. And if there's nothing in the input, then I want the SAME placeholder in a different color and with a different message. And if the API found a word, I want that placeholder gone and replaced with the definition. A lot of CSS styles are always changing.

Do I always have to `name.style.color` or `name.style.display` anytime something changes? It's getting to the point where I have like five lines dedicated to changing the styles. Is this normal? Something like:

```
    this.phonetic.innerHTML = '';
    this.definition.innerHTML = '';
    // Get rid of placeholder
    this.placeholder.style.display = 'none';
    //Remove flex properties
    this.definitionDiv.style.display = 'block'
```

Is there a way to list a list of specific CSS values and apply them when I call upon a certain function?

P.S. Does the above method impact performance?

Comment: Build your own js function or if possible, use jQuery

Comment: Handle your UI updates with utility classes instead, then you can declare all the relevant style rules you need to the given element for the given situation. `element.classList.add('classname')` or `element.classList.remove('classname')`, for conditional evaluation: `element.classList.contains('classname')`.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Frameworks like Angular offer interpolation, so it would be "smarter" (i.e. you could use ternaries instead of listening for changes and writing code to handle them - the framework does the job for you), but it's way bulkier than plain HTML, JS and CSS. Even then they are quite fast and modern browsers and PCs handle them just fine (those few lines of code you presented are way lighter and probably faster than that).

Comment: In terms of performance, you'll be causing repaints and possibly reflows with every css change or DOM update. The performance impact should be negligible, you'd have to have many lines of javascript updating the DOM sequentially before you begin to notice it blocking the UI. Still it doesn't mean you shouldn't try to prematurely optimise it in this case. Using a class would be more efficient and performant than directly updating the DOM with inline styles, it also mitigates javascript's footprint on the DOM.

Comment: You also get to leverage all the inherent CSS cascade and specificity advantages when using external styles through classes - giving you much more control over your styling and how your elements behave in general.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError - the OP wants to change the  placeholder's content. I think updating classes sounds like good practice CSS-wise, but you can't change placeholder contents with CSS alone.

Comment: @gyohza Yes, I'm speaking specifically to handling css updates, as there is that aspect to the OP's question as well, not actual DOM content. Maybe the OP can clarify in this regard, I get the impression from the question being asked that the DOM updating is not the focus here, "A lot of CSS styles are always changing.", and "Is there a way to list a list of specific CSS values and apply them when I call upon a certain function?"

Comment: @gyohza — thanks for the reply. Perhaps I should revise my question, but it's both the placeholder and its styles that I want to change. I'm not using any frameworks, as I just want to focus on pure JS.